# Overload resolution of template methods with ref-qualifiers

Tags: c++, visual-c++, language-lawyer

I'm developing a container with compile-time access function using special type. I also want to have an access function using a number in order to implement ops for all elements. Thus I have something like this:

```
struct S
{
    template<int I> int& f();
    template<class Q> int& f();
};
```

I want to forbid access for temporary objects, so I add an overload for type-access:

```
struct S
{
    template<int I> int& f();
    template<class Q> int& f() &;
    template<class Q> int& f() && = delete;
};
```

But then I have a problem with msvc compiler:

```
<source>(4): error C2560: 'int &Test::f(void) &': cannot overload a member function with ref-qualifier with a member function without ref-qualifier
```

However both gcc and clang accept it. Who is right?

https://godbolt.org/z/4bmA2-

Comment: When both gcc and clang agree, and msvc disagrees, most of the time it is a msvc bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSVC is wrong here.

The relevant rule is [[over.load]/2.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.load#2.3):

> Member function declarations with the same name and the same parameter-type-list as well as member function template declarations with the same name, the same parameter-type-list, **and the same template parameter lists** cannot be overloaded if any of them, but not all, have a ref-qualifier ([dcl.fct]).

Here the function templates have different template parameters (`int I` and `class Q`), so this rule does not apply, and there is no other rule stoping them from overloading.

Answer (score 1):

MSVC is correct here. You cannot have a both a ref-qualifier and a non-ref-qualifier overload.

Why not? Because they are ambiguous. A ref-qualified member function has a qualifier specifying whether the object pointed to by `this` is an lvalue (`&`) or an rvalue (`&&`). Meanwhile, a non-ref-qualified member function accepts *both* lvalues *and* rvalues. This creates an ambiguity, which the compiler treats as an error.

Note that the `template` aspect of this code is a red herring. You'd have just as much trouble with the simpler:

```
struct S
{
    int& f();       // non-ref-qualifier
    int& f() &;     // ref-qualifier (this must be lvalue)
    int& f() &&;    // ref-qualifier (this must be rvalue)
};
```

or even just:

```
struct S
{
    int& f();       // non-ref-qualifier
    int& f() &;     // ref-qualifier (this must be lvalue)
};
```

The C++14 language standard defines the semantics of candidate resolution for ref-qualified member functions in [over.match.funcs](http://timepp.github.io/doc/cpp14/over.match.funcs.html). Specifically, §13.3.1 [4]:

> For non-static member functions, the type of the implicit object parameter is
>
> - “lvalue reference to *cv* `X`” for functions declared without a *ref-qualifier* or with the & ref-qualifier
> - “rvalue reference to *cv* `X`” for functions declared with the && *ref-qualifier*
>
> where `X` is the class of which the function is a member and *cv* is the cv-qualification on the member function declaration. [ *Example:* For a `const` member function of `class X`, the extra parameter is assumed to have type “reference to `const X`”. — *end example* ] For conversion functions, the function is considered to be a member of the class of the implied object argument for the purpose of defining the type of the implicit object parameter. For non-conversion functions introduced by a *using-declaration* into a derived class, the function is considered to be a member of the derived class for the purpose of defining the type of the implicit object parameter. For static member functions, the implicit object parameter is considered to match any object (since if the function is selected, the object is discarded). [ *Note*: No actual type is established for the implicit object parameter of a static member function, and no attempt will be made to determine a conversion sequence for that parameter ([over.match.best]). — *end note* ]

and §13.4.1 [5] (emphasis added):

> **During overload resolution, the implied object argument is indistinguishable from other arguments.** The implicit object parameter, however, retains its identity since no user-defined conversions can be applied to achieve a type match with it. **For non-static member functions declared without a *ref-qualifier*, an additional rule applies:**
>
> - even if the implicit object parameter is not const-qualified, **an rvalue can be bound to the parameter as long as in all other respects the argument can be converted to the type of the implicit object parameter**. [ *Note*: The fact that such an argument is an rvalue does not affect the ranking of implicit conversion sequences. — *end note* ]

MSVC has two warnings specifically for this ref-qualifier overload ambiguity:

> - Compiler Error **C2559**
>   '*identifier*': cannot overload a member function without ref-qualifier with a member function with ref-qualifier
> - Compiler Error **C2560**
>   '*identifier*': cannot overload a member function with ref-qualifier with a member function without ref-qualifier

To forbid calls to the member function on temporary objects (rvalues), it is therefore sufficient to just do:

```
struct S
{
    int& f() &;            // ref-qualifier (this must be lvalue)
    int& f() && = delete;  // ref-qualifier (this must be rvalue)
};
```

or, with the templates:

```
struct S
{
    template<int I> int& f() &;
    template<int I> int& f() && = delete;

    template<class Q> int& f() &;
    template<class Q> int& f() && = delete;
};
```

Comment: msvc is not right. This is not the same function that is overloaded. The template arguments are not the same

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer however I don't think template is irrelevant here. Quite the contrary! With regular methods the problem is clear for me, but with essentially different template parameters (type and integral constant) it's not. I mean I didn't expect this is an overload.

Comment: _Because they are ambiguous._ Ambiguity is when an overload resolution can't select a function. In a calls `E1.f<42>()` or `E1.f<char>()`, there is no ambiguity because only specializations of either `template<int I> int& f()` or `template<class Q> int& f()` participate in overload resolution.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer because both of them accept the original code (and also icc).

Comment: @GenaBug but I believe they should.

Comment: Oops, sorry, @LanguageLawyer, didn't  understand you! Thus you believe it's msvc bug, right? I also think it's a bug in msvc, just want to be sure.